# Issues with File Copy Asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, concurrency, task

I am copying files asynchronously with the article Microsoft provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o

The issue I am running into using this is that when the files are finished copying, it doesn't keep the date modified value and is set to the time the file was created.

To compensate for that, I am trying to set the date modified time for each file after their finished copying with the `File.SetLastWriteTime` static method.

```
foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles())
{
    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
    using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(temppath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            await reader.CopyToAsync(writer);
            File.SetLastWriteTime(temppath, file.LastWriteTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the `File.SetLastWriteTime` method executes immediately before `await reader.CopyToAsync(writer)` has finished.

How can I make sure that the `File.SetLastWriteTime` method isn't executed until after `reader.CopyToAsync` has finished?

It appears to work as intended if I change the method to copy synchronously within a `Task.Run`, but not sure if that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: "Unfortunately, it seems that the File.SetLastWriteTime method executes immediately before await reader.CopyToAsync(writer) has finished." Are you sure? What system behavior do you experience that leads you to say that?

Comment: _"How can I make sure that the File.SetLastWriteTime method isn't executed until after reader.CopyToAsync has finished?"_ -- the code you posted does that. So if you have a problem, it's likely in the code you didn't post. Your question should include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Or, maybe you should try the `File.Copy()` method (run it using `Task.Run()` to get async behavior).

Comment: I get a message that it couldn't set the time on the file because it was being used by another process.

Comment: I would just use `File.Copy` wrapped in a `Task.Run`, that keeps the original attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

The reason why it couldn't set the file time is because it was still within the stream.

I simply moved the method outside of the write stream and that resolved the problem.

```
       foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles())
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(temppath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await reader.CopyToAsync(writer);

                }
               File.SetLastWriteTime(temppath, file.LastWriteTime);
            }
        }
```